# Получить тип наследника из родителя C#

Tags: c#, наследование, рефлексия

Доброго времени, возникла необходимость получить тип дочернего объекта из его родителя, связанно это с тем, что я использую EntityFramework и при "Материализации" данных вешаю на событие, обработчик, который принимает эту сущность

```
((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized +=
            (sender, e) =>
            {
                DateTimeKind.Apply(e.Entity);
            };
```

и в своем теле, пытается получить соответствующий элемент из generic коллекции. Для наглядности

```
abstract class BaseDateTimeDescriptor
{

}
class DateTimeDescriptor<TEntity> : BaseDateTimeDescriptor
{
    public DateTimeDescriptor(Func<TEntity, PropertyInfo> selector)
    {
        FieldInfo = selector;
    }
    public Func<TEntity, PropertyInfo> FieldInfo { get; set; }
}

class DateTimeConfigurator
{
    static DateTimeConfigurator()
    {
        Descriptors = new Dictionary<Type, BaseDateTimeDescriptor>();
    }
    //меня тут вынуждают создать BaseDateTimeDescriptor, т.к. я не могу просто так написать DateTimeDescriptor<TEntity>
    public static Dictionary<Type, BaseDateTimeDescriptor> Descriptors { get; set; }
    public static void Add<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, PropertyInfo> selector)
    {
        Descriptors.Add(typeof(TEntity), new DateTimeDescriptor<TEntity>(selector));
    }
}
```

Как видите я использую словарь, значениями элементов которого являются базовые классы. Но я всегда, при вызове метода Add из DateTimeConfigurator создаю экземпляр наследника.
Уже в самом методе-обработчике я получаю эту коллекцию

```
public static void Apply<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    {
        var descriptor = DateTimeConfigurator.Descriptors.Where(x => x.Key == entity.GetType()).First();
        //тут я получаю первый попавшийся дескриптор из "словаря", который соответствует типу entity
        var fieldDescriptor = descriptor.Value as DateTimeDescriptor<TEntity>; //поскольку EntityFramework передась entity как object, то и будет попытка привестить к object, которая вернет Null 
        var date = fieldDescriptor.FieldInfo.Invoke(entity); //И тут выкидывает nullrefexception
    }
```

и пытаюсь привести базовый класс к наследнику, что бы получить доступ к "FieldInfo", но из-за того, что TEntity имеет тип object, то и приведение происходит не корректно(возвращает null). 
У меня 2 вопроса по этому поводу. Можно ли в обработчик передать правильный тип, а не object? Или уже в самом обработчике извлечь тип entity и передать его в оператор приведения

```
var fieldDescriptor = descriptor.Value as DateTimeDescriptor<Каким-то образом верно определенный тип сущности>
```

Comment: а какой реальный тип _descriptor.Value_?

Comment: DateTimeDescriptor<TEntity>

Comment: В классе DateTimeConfigurator есть метод Add, который создает и добавляет экземпляр наследника

Comment: нет, реальный - это тип в момент выполнения, там уже определен `TEntity`, скорее всего реальный `TEntity` не совпадает с тем. к которому идет попытка приведения, поэтому в результате Null

Comment: Если я напишу явный тип, например var fieldDescriptor = descriptor.Value as DateTimeDescriptor<MyType> то все будет нормально, но дело в том что из базы достаются разные типы (в зависимости от таблицы с которой я достаю) поэтому нужен универсальный способ

Comment: Относительно вашего последнего комментария, реальный тип динамически изменяется, т.к. entity framework постоянно вызывает этот метод для каждой сущности

Comment: об этом и речь. кто и как вызывает `DateTimeConfigurator.Add`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48144/discussion-between-grundy-and-simply-good).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как в generic-метод передается переменная с типом object, то внутри функции TEntity будет Object, и

```
DateTimeDescriptor<TEntity>
```

Вместо ожидаемого типа будет

```
DateTimeDescriptor<object>
```

В качестве обходного пути можно использовать рефлексию при вызове.

Вместо данной строки

```
DateTimeKind.Apply(e.Entity);
```

Будет так

```
typeof(DateTimeKind).GetMethod("Apply", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public) // берем публичный статический метод Apply
    .MakeGenericMethod(e.Entity.GetType()) // на его основе создаем generic меток с конкретным типом
    .Invoke(null, new[] { e.Entity }); // вызываем полученный метод
```